# Unable to search for videos of a particular channel using youtube Data API (v3)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to obtain the list of all videos of a particular channel (Hindi Movies - https://www.youtube.com/channel/SBa1uR1yU6EZA )

The query I tried in the API explorer is :

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=SBa1uR1yU6EZA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Expected Result: It shows only results from the specified channel.
What happens: It shows millions of results from various channels.

However the API explorer is able to fetch videos of another channel(https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCU8LF98Njvux51LYGLgXiaw) just fine. ( channelID has been changed in this query):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCU8LF98Njvux51LYGLgXiaw&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

So is it possible to only fetch  videos shown in the channel (Hindi Movies) ? If so how ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Expected Result: It shows only results from the specified channel.
>   What happens: It shows millions of results from various channels.

Hindi Movies is not a "normal" channel like YRF Movies. This channel is created by Google Play to present you some paid content.

In this channel, there is no videos ! it's just a link to other channel. This is why you get "millions of results from various channels"

No weird things, the API answer is fine.